# Неверный порядок сортировки списка строк в python

Tags: python, строки, сортировка

Доброго времени суток. Я совсем недавно начал изучать python, поэтому прошу не кидать камнями, если я упускаю что-то очевидное. Гугл с моим вопросом не помог. Дело в том, что сортировка списка строк, которая, по идее, должна проводиться по алфавиту, но у меня происходит не совсем по нему. И я никак не пойму, отчего так. Вот есть, допустим, у меня такой код

```
inp = open("input", "r")
outp = open("output", "w")
lst = inp.read().split()
lst.sort()
for elem in lst:
    outp.write(str(elem) + "\n")
inp.close()
outp.close()
```

В файле input у меня набор слов, по слову на каждой строке. Допустим, есть файл с такими данными(просто белиберда для проверки):

```
авыаы
мрпр
квуенуке
авпвке
цуеек
авыронг
авроанг
аыуке
гекекы
енгнкекв
ывавкеекц
огшдн
цййап
выама
пенк
иаапре
аукег
венгера
вкыкавп43у
авапнеанне
ноорвап
ававыпен
```

А в файле output я получаю вот это:

```
ававыпен
авапнеанне
авпвке
авроанг
авыаы
авыронг
аукег
аыуке
енгнкекв
ноорвап
венгера
вкыкавп43у
выама
иаапре
квуенуке
огшдн
гекекы
пенк
мрпр
цййап
цуеек
ывавкеекц
```

Ну вот какого черта, например, "венгера" идет после "ноорвап", ведь слова на букву "в" должны находиться перед словами на букву "н"? Также выходит, что слова на букву "и" идут после слов на букву "к", что, очевидно, неверно. И т.д. и т.п. Вроде бы слова на одну и ту же букву действительно "собрались вместе", то есть сортировка по алфавиту была произведена, вот только алфавит какой-то не такой. Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, что я делаю не так.

Update: Когда я решил просто вывести отсортированные буквы алфавита то получил это:

```
а б е ж з л н в и к о г п м д й р с ъ ь ю э я у т ф ц ч х щ ы ш
```

У python какой-то непонятно откуда взявшийся свой алфавит. Что это вообще значит?

При попытке сменить локаль при помощи `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')` python выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "search2.py", line 24, in <module>
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')
  File 
"C:\Users\andre\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\locale.py", line 
598, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

Comment: попробуйте использовать локальный язык в сортировке `sorted(mylist, key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36139/how-to-sort-a-list-of-strings

Comment: Использование локального языка никак не влияет на вывод

Comment: Вы неверно указали локаль. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting Необходимо указать `'ru_RU.utf8'`

Comment: С этим вариантом возникает точно такая же ошибка

Comment: Какой питон используете? Пишите пожалуйста *@nickname* перед тем как написать сообщение человеку. В противном случае рискуете остаться без ответа. Так как он его не увидит

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваш файл `input` сохранён в кодировке UTF-8.

Когда вы не указываете кодировку файла явно в методе `open`, питон для чтения или записи файла выбирает некую кодировку по умолчанию, которая зависит от системы.

В вашем случае в винде этой кодировкой оказалась не UTF-8, а cp1251.

В результате питон прочитал ваш файл в неправильной кодировке, и получилось вот так:

```
Р°РІС‹Р°С‹
РјСЂРїСЂ
РєРІСѓРµРЅСѓРєРµ
Р°РІРїРІРєРµ
С†СѓРµРµРє
Р°РІС‹СЂРѕРЅРі
Р°РІСЂРѕР°РЅРі
Р°С‹СѓРєРµ
РіРµРєРµРєС‹
РµРЅРіРЅРєРµРєРІ
С‹РІР°РІРєРµРµРєС†
РѕРіС€РґРЅ
С†Р№Р№Р°Рї
РІС‹Р°РјР°
РїРµРЅРє
РёР°Р°РїСЂРµ
Р°СѓРєРµРі
РІРµРЅРіРµСЂР°
РІРєС‹РєР°РІРї43Сѓ
Р°РІР°РїРЅРµР°РЅРЅРµ
РЅРѕРѕСЂРІР°Рї
Р°РІР°РІС‹РїРµРЅ
```

Соответственно и правила сортировки изменились.

Наиболее простым и предпочтительным способом исправления этого будет явное указание кодировки файла при чтении:

```
inp = open("input", "r", encoding="utf-8-sig")
```

(Я указал `utf-8-sig` вместо `utf-8`, чтобы питон нормально обработал [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), который любит добавлять виндовый Блокнот.)

Да и для записи желательно проделать то же самое:

```
outp = open("output", "w", encoding="utf-8")
```

(Здесь я указал `utf-8` вместо `utf-8-sig`, чтобы BOM в выходной файл не добавлялся. Можете изменить это на свой вкус.)

Если вы хотите использовать другие кодировки в своих файлах, замените их на свои соответственно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Помогло. Просто при выводе в файл все символы отображаются верно, поэтому не подумал даже, что изначально из input всё читалось не в той кодировке

Comment: @AndrewV если закодировать эти строки вида `Р°РІС‹Р°С‹` обратно с кодировкой cp1251, то по «счастливой случайности» получится корректная последовательность UTF-8. То приложение, с помощью которого вы смотрели файл `output` (наверно, это был Блокнот?) распознало это как UTF-8 и смог раскодировать как  UTF-8 :) В принципе, питон тоже можно научить автоматически распознавать кодировку файла вместо явного прописывания в `open` точно так же, как это делают Блокнот и другие текстовые редакторы, но это требует дополнительных действий и дополнительных библиотек и выходит за рамки данного вопроса.

Comment: @AndrewV кстати, в таком «наивном» варианте сортировки `ё` будет больше(!) чем `я`, так что возможно информация из соседнего ответа вам тоже пригодится :)

Answer (score 1):

Основной ответ:

```
mylist = ["b", "C", "A"]
mylist.sort()
```

Это изменяет исходный список. Чтобы получить отсортированную копию списка без изменения оригинала, используйте функцию sorted ():

```
for x in sorted(mylist):
    print x
```

Однако приведенные выше примеры немного наивны, потому что они не учитывают языковой стандарт и выполняют сортировку по регистру. Вы можете воспользоваться опциональным ключом параметра, чтобы указать пользовательский порядок сортировки (например, использование `cmp` является устаревшим решением, поскольку его нужно оценивать несколько раз - ключ вычисляется только один раз для каждого элемента).

Итак, для сортировки в соответствии с текущей локалью, принимая во внимание специфические для языка правила (`cmp_to_key` - вспомогательная функция от `functools`):

```
sorted(mylist, key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll))
```

И, наконец, если вам нужно, вы можете указать пользовательскую локаль для сортировки:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8') # vary depending on your lang/locale
assert sorted(
    (u'Ab', u'ad', u'aa'), 
    key=cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll)
) == [u'aa', u'Ab', u'ad']
```

Последнее замечание: вы можете глянуть примеры нечувствительности к регистру сортировки, которые используют метод `lower()` - они неверны, поскольку работают только для подмножества символов *ASCII*. Эти два неверны для любых неанглийских данных:

```
# this is incorrect!
mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x.lower())
# alternative notation, a bit faster, but still wrong
mylist.sort(key=str.lower)
```

Замечание. В некоторых случаях локаль следует указывать как:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.utf8')
```

Comment: Да, сверху уже кидали ссылку на этот текст, только на английском. Как я уже писал, использование cmp_to_key(locale.strcoll) ни на что не повлияло. А когда я пытаюсь установить локаль ru_RU.UTF-8, то python вовсе выдает ошибку

Comment: @AndrewV я не видел вашего коммента

Comment: @AndrewV добавьте пример кода, как Вы выставляете локаль

Comment: `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8')`

Comment: @AndrewV Ошибка какая? Добавьте в свой вопрос это. Отредактируйте его.